# Rails: best_in_place collection issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, namespaces, best-in-place

My app runs on two different database, and I use the application logic to work on them.

I have the **User model** on an **external db** and I only records the **id** on my **default_role class**.

So in the index template I fetch the accounts from remote, and for each of them **I have to query my table** to print some immutable information and I want to give the possibility to **change role in my table**

Index information = remote tables information (name surname ecc) + my table information (role)

Using best_in_place to edit the role_id field of my users.

**The problem is my index cycle @operators which comes from outside buy I need to change role which is on my side!**

```
- @operators.each do |ope|   #cycle users
      %tr
        %td
          - user = User.find_by_bay_id(ope.account_id)
          - df = DefaultRole.find_by_operator_id(user.id)
          = best_in_place [:admin, df], :role_id, :type => :select, :collection => [[1, 'admin'], [2, 'coordinator'], [3, 'operator'], [4, 'base']]
```

and my update in controller:

```
respond_to :html, :json

def index
  @operators = some logic from model where I get all the users
end

def update
  @df = DefaultRole.find(params[:id])
  @df.update_attributes(params[:default_role])
  respond_with [:admin, @df]
end
```

But it didn't even call my update method in the controller.
It normally checks the collection tag, allows me to change it but it doesn't allow me to submit.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

My browser doesn't catch any request.

Comment: Post your `update` action from the controller .

Comment: I think if you would like to modify Admin model , you should use `= best_in_place @admin, ....` and pass the default in `:html_attrs` hash.

Comment: Edited question to better explain why I can't do that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the error.

https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place/issues/217

It was a Jquery issue on that version of best_in_place. Running:

`bundle update`

and restarting the server solve the problem, thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

Best_in_place gem uses JSON calls to update the content . In this case you should have `respond_to json` statement in your controller , something like this :

```
def update
 @df = DefaultRole.find(params[:id])
respond_to do |format|
  if @df.update_attributes(params[:default_role])
    format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Role was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  else
    format.html { render action: "edit" }
    format.json { render json: @df.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end 
end
```

I find it strange to include variable specifications in your view , they belong to the controller (`- user = User.find_by_bay_id(ope.account_id)
          - df = DefaultRole.find_by_operator_id(user.id)` .

Comment: Yes I forgot to add this in the question text, but I already had it on the top of the controller, sorry

Comment: It should be into the action `update` , not at the top of the controller.

Comment: I think it's ok using the respond_with after declaring in the top what it will handle. By the way it doesn't even call the update action, so this will eventually be a problem later right?

Comment: That's how the best_in_place gem is designed - it calls the update behind the scenes...

Comment: Ok but server's log doesn't show anything. By the way I tried your solution and it doesn't work either. There is something I am missing even because I used bip gem tons of time. This is just a different case then tipic ones